# Connection Verification Failed while attempting to verify mail setting in ColdFusion 10 administrator

Tags: coldfusion, smtp, coldfusion-10, cfmail

I am using ColdFusion 10 in windows server 2008 R2. In administrator, i am getting connection error while verifying the mail server settings.

I am using the below settings,

```
server : smtp.gmail.com 
port: 465
Username : testuser@gmail.com 
password: xxxxxxxx
```

and checked Enable SSL socket connection to mail server.

With this settings, i am getting the error "Connection Verification Failed !".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have also faced this same issue and solved it by changing the port from 465 to 587.

In ColdFusion Administrator check the 'Enable TLS Connection to mail server' check box and  remove check from 'Enable SSL connection to mail server'.

Now you can verify the connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the 'Enable TLS Connection to mail server' checkbox as well.

I was unable to verify the connection on my test server using the settings you have specified - but using my own credentials.

I was able to verify connection when TLS was enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Removing username and password worked for me in CF11.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this issue a lot recently, due to Google making some changes to the way that you access GMail accounts.

Specifically, you may find a setting in your account that refers to allowing access to 'Less secure apps'.
Essentially, Google are trying to force oAuth style authentication, and denying access via username/password auth.

You can re-enable the 'less secure' method of authentication in your account settings:
http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: This. I have the same settings as the OP as shown in his question and I was getting a 'Connection Verification Failed!' message when saving the settings in the CF admin panel. This fixed it for me. Although now unfortunately my gmail is less secure :(

Comment: Your Gmail is no less secure using this method - the language is misleading. What it means is that this method of authentication (uname/pass) requires that you trust the third party app (in this instance, your ColdFusion app) completely. oAuth is preferred, because it grants access for the app, but without trusting it... if you *wrote* the app, however.... ;)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, double check your SSL/TLS options and port numbers. Also check for leading/trailing spaces in your SMTP credentials. I spent 20 mins troubleshooting this issue once and it turned out to be caused by a trailing space in the SMTP username field.. :/